# Comparing SEM with categorical response variables

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I am working with a dataset with an endogenous categorical variable. I wish to determine whether removing a path from the model has a significant effect in the model. I read that the appropriate way of doing this is to fit a `sem` with and without the path and then compare them using AIC values. However I am encountering a problem. Code below:

```
*Note1 -  "Tr" is an ordered categorical variable

corkoak6590$Tr <- ordered(corkoak6590$Tr,levels = c("dec","per","inc"))

*Note2 - "Fire" denotes presence/absence and is coded as 1/0 (as a numerical variable)

model<-"Tr~slope+Pop71+Trendpop71_91+Fire+TempWA+SDII+TXx+WSDI+CDD
Fire~Trendpop71_91+TempWA+Prec+WSDI+slope+SDII+TXx"


model1<-"Tr~slope+Pop71+Trendpop71_91+Fire+SDII+WSDI+CDD+TXx
Fire~Trendpop71_91+TempWA+Prec+WSDI+slope+SDII+TXx"

(TempWA was removed from the first line in model1)

fit1<-sem(model, data=data_corkoak6590)
fit2<-sem(model1, data=data_corkoak6590)

show(fit1)
lavaan (0.5-22) converged normally after  39 iterations

  Number of observations                         10573

  Estimator                                       DWLS      Robust
  Minimum Function Test Statistic                5.463       5.464
  Degrees of freedom                                 3           3
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.141       0.141
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.000
  Shift parameter                                            0.001
    for simple second-order correction (Mplus variant)

show(fit2)

lavaan (0.5-22) converged normally after  37 iterations

  Number of observations                         10573

  Estimator                                       DWLS      Robust
  Minimum Function Test Statistic                8.579       8.553
  Degrees of freedom                                 4           4
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.073       0.073
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.007
  Shift parameter                                            0.038
    for simple second-order correction (Mplus variant)


fitmeasures(fit1,"aic")
aic 
 NA 

fitmeasures(fit2,"aic")
aic 
 NA 

anova(fit1,fit2)
Error in lav_test_diff_af_h1(m1 = m1, m0 = m0) : 
  lavaan ERROR: unconstrained parameter set is not the same in m0 and m1
```

I wonder why the AIC is NA. Feels like something went terribly wrong.

I found a similar situation in a dataset on this presentation:

http://www.personality-project.org/r/tutorials/summerschool.14/rosseel_sem_cat.pdf

```
table.7.5 <-read.table("http://www.da.ugent.be/datasets/Agresti2002.Table.7.5.dat",header=TRUE)

table.7.5$mental <- ordered(table.7.5$mental,levels = c("well","mild","moderate","impaired"))

model <- "mental ~ ses + life"

fit <- sem(model, data=table.7.5)

summary(fit,rsq=TRUE,standardized=T,modindices=TRUE)
fitmeasures(fit,"aic")
fitmeasures(fit)

npar                          fmin                         chisq 
                        5.000                         0.000                         0.000 
                           df                        pvalue                  chisq.scaled 
                        0.000                            NA                         0.000 
                    df.scaled                 pvalue.scaled          chisq.scaling.factor 
                        0.000                            NA                            NA 
               baseline.chisq                   baseline.df               baseline.pvalue 
                       11.141                         2.000                         0.004 
        baseline.chisq.scaled            baseline.df.scaled        baseline.pvalue.scaled 
                       10.897                         2.000                         0.004 
baseline.chisq.scaling.factor                           cfi                           tli 
                        1.033                         1.000                         1.000 
                         nnfi                           rfi                           nfi 
                        1.000                         1.000                         1.000 
                         pnfi                           ifi                           rni 
                        0.000                         1.000                         1.000 
                   cfi.scaled                    tli.scaled                    cfi.robust 
                        1.000                         1.000                            NA 
                   tli.robust                   nnfi.scaled                   nnfi.robust 
                           NA                         1.000                            NA 
                   rfi.scaled                    nfi.scaled                    ifi.scaled 
                        1.000                         1.000                         1.000 
                   rni.scaled                    rni.robust                         rmsea 
                        1.000                            NA                         0.000 
               rmsea.ci.lower                rmsea.ci.upper                  rmsea.pvalue 
                        0.000                         0.000                            NA 
                 rmsea.scaled         rmsea.ci.lower.scaled         rmsea.ci.upper.scaled 
                        0.000                         0.000                         0.000 
          rmsea.pvalue.scaled                  rmsea.robust         rmsea.ci.lower.robust 
                           NA                            NA                         0.000 
        rmsea.ci.upper.robust           rmsea.pvalue.robust                           rmr 
                        0.000                            NA                         0.000 
                   rmr_nomean                          srmr                  srmr_bentler 
                        0.000                         0.000                         0.000 
          srmr_bentler_nomean                   srmr_bollen            srmr_bollen_nomean 
                        0.000                         0.000                         0.000 
                   srmr_mplus             srmr_mplus_nomean                         cn_05 
                        0.000                         0.000                            NA 
                        cn_01                           gfi                          agfi 
                           NA                         1.000                         1.000 
                         pgfi                           mfi 
                        0.000                         1.000
```

Thanks

Comment: I think we need to see more code to diagnose the problem. Can we see the code that gerarated model and model1?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this. I edited the question and added the code.

Comment: What happens with the anova command now? (My hard disk just died, so I can't try it out. :( ).

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I added the output of the anova command

Comment: This is a different error from last time, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to point that out. Unfortunately I can't replicate the previous error message. I tried different combinations of variables but I am only getting this message.

Comment: I think the other error message was because of a typo somewhere.

Comment: I've moved this discussion to chat: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258506/comparing-sem-with-categorical-response-variables

Comment: Sorry, but I was not aware that SE has a chat feature. Anyway I haven't received any notification. Where should I look for that feature? Tks

Comment: Sorry, posted wrong link: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52691/discussion-on-anova-and-lavaan